# Rename multiple files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have `A.js`, `B.js`, `C.js` in a certain directory and I want to write a SINGLE command line in bash shell to rename these files _A, _B, _C. How can I do this?

I tried `find -name '*.sh' | xargs -I file mv file basename file .sh` but it doesn't work, basename file .sh isn't recognized as a nested command

Comment: I tried find -name '*.sh' | xargs -I file mv file `basename file .sh`
but it doesn't work, basename file .sh isn't recognized as a nested command

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the FAQ and possibly http://whathaveyoutried.com, and then edit your question.

Comment: I read that article, and you are right, the writer of the article is also right. But if you have to solve 10 problems and the solution to one of them creates a new problem (in my case rename this files) and you have very few time (because your boss is waiting for a solution to all of the 10 problems) will you ask directly for the solution or for an approach to solve it without a precise solution? The latter maybe is better, but if you have very few time? I think that sometimes ask only for the solution is necessary.
Regards and thank you for pointing out this issue to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
rename 's/(.*).js/_$1/' *.js
```

Check the syntax for rename on your system.

The above command will rename `A.js` to `_A` & so on.

If you want to retain the extension, below should help:

```
rename 's/(.*)/_$1/' *.js
```

Comment: +1 because rename is a good tool. FYI, it is written in Perl so the syntax is uniform across systems http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL

Comment: @msw: No, the syntax may be different. I have seen syntax - `'rename "from_regex" "to_string" files_filter'` instead of `rename 's/from_regex/to_string/' files_filter`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you still want to keep the extension on the files, you could do this:

```
$ for f in * ; do mv "$f" _"$f" ; done
```

It will get the name of each file in the directory, and prepend an "_".

Comment: If I understood him right, he wants to remove the file extension as well.

Comment: thank you very much! 
I modified the code this way:
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "_$(basename $f .sh)" ; done
and it works well!

Comment: @user1703524 That's great! I was actually just about to edit the post in almost a very similar way to what you just did. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

A simple native way to do it, with **directory traversal**:

```
find -type f | xargs -I {} mv {} {}.txt
```

Will rename every file in place adding extension .txt at the end.

And a more general cool way with **parallelization**:

```
find -name "file*.p" | parallel 'f="{}" ; mv -- {} ${f:0:4}change_between${f:8}'
```